# Check if array content an object using include

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following array on my rails console:

```
u.favorites

[#<Favorite id: 20, candidate_id: 6, ...>, #<Favorite id: 21, candidate_id: 7,..">, #<Favorite id: 22, candidate_id: 8, ...">, #<Favorite id: 23, candidate_id: 9, ...">, #<Favorite id: 24, candidate_id: 10, ...">]
```

As you can see, I have candidate_id:6, candidate_id:7, candidate_id:8, candidate_id:9, candidate_id:10. But if I try this:

u.favorites.include?(:candidate_id => 5) o canidate 6, 7, 8, 9 or 10 I get false.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
u.favorites.select{|f| f.candidate_id==5}.any?
```

or

```
u.favorites.collect(&:candidate_id).include?(5)
```